# Input type radio scales up when more text is added

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs, radio-button

Here is part of my code:

```
<FormGroup>
    <Radio name="radioGroup" inline>
        Osoba prywatna (do 1000zl miesiecznie)
    </Radio>{' '}
    <Radio name="radioGroup" inline>
        Firma (Powyzej 1000zl miesiecznie)
    </Radio>{' '}
    <Radio name="radioGroup" inline>
        3
    </Radio>
</FormGroup>
```

I'm using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/) to render the `Radio` element, but same thing happens with

```
<label for='radio'>this is a very long text, which will show my point</label>
<input id='radio' type='radio'/>`
```

When the description/label is longer, the radio button scales up. Like this:

Example with `Radio` component

[image]

Example with `<label>` and `<input/>`

[image]
Why is this happening? And how can I prevent it?

Comment: I think it happens because label  take two lines and  circle fill all  empty space. So if I'm right you need to  trim  label text or  do  it ellipsis

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate your issue in [this sandbox editor](https://codesandbox.io/s/3xv8742w41). Is it possible you've accidentally given your radio button the `display: inline-flex` property? In addition, make sure you're not using bootstrap 4.0.0, which [react-table does not support](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Turns out this was caused by a theme I used on my Linux machine... (Adwaita-dark) I doubt anyone will hit this issue, but it might save someone in a couple of years. Feel free to close as

> a problem that can no longer be reproduced